# Swift UI Lifecycle: how to replace the current view with a new one ? Not simply pushing it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application created following the SwiftUI lifecycle. I'm able to push new views without problems but I can't figure out how to replace a view.
What I need to achieve is what I was able to do in the AppDelegate lifecycle with this code

```
let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
self.window = UIWindow(frame: bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I tried both to replace the root view and to dismiss the old view while pushing the new one but I can't find a working solution.

I tried to use

```
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

but it doesn't work if I try to dismiss the view just before, or after, I push the new one.

I don't know if I'm missing something.

**EDIT**

I tried to implemented the the solution with the ViewGroup

```
import SwiftUI

// Specify all root level screens
enum Screen {
    case login
    case users
}

@main
struct IosstarterkitApp: App {
    var loginV: AnyView
    var userV: AnyView
    // Use @State for current screen
    @State var screen: Screen = .login

    init() {

        // instantiate the factory for the dependency injection
        let baseProviderFactory: BaseProviderProtocol = BaseProviderFactory()
        
        // Create the SwiftUI views that provides the window contents.
        var userView = UserView(store: UserStore())
        userView.setPresenter(presenter: baseProviderFactory.getUserPresenter() as! BasePresenterProtocol)
        userV = AnyView(userView)
        var loginView = LoginView(store: LoginStore())
        loginView.setPresenter(presenter: baseProviderFactory.getLoginPresenter() as! BasePresenterProtocol)
        loginV = AnyView(loginView)

        let userDefaultRepository = UserDefaultsRepository()
        if userDefaultRepository.getAccessToken() != nil {
            self.screen = .users
        } else {
            self.screen = .login
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch screen {
            case .login:
                RootView(view: loginV)
            case .users:
                RootView(view: userV)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to update the screen variable, based on the token presence, the variable is not getting updated. I'm trying to show a view or another based on the condition that the user is logged.
Moreover I need to update the screen variable from another view (like the LoginView) that is in another file. How can I do it ?

Comment: Try with a state var (enum or bool) you can use to select the view to be displayed.

Comment: Try reading more about @State: https://swiftui-lab.com/state-changes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you want to replace a root view of the app. Here is the simple example how to do it by using SwiftUI app life-cycle:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Specify all root level screens
enum Screen {
    case onboarding
    case home
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    // Use @State for current screen
    @State var screen: Screen = .onboarding

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch screen {
            case .onboarding:
                OnboardingView {
                    screen = .home
                }
            case .home:
                HomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OnboardingView: View {
    let openHome: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("OnboardingView")
            Button("Open Home") {
                openHome()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("HomeView")
    }
}
```

You can consider the `MyApp: App` as a regular `View` in `SwiftUI` where you can replace any root views using state.

**EDIT**

This is an update version of the code. It's use very basic implementation of the Coordinator. Here Coordinator is also a factory for creating views. For more advanced info please search for MVVM with Coordinator specific for SwiftUI.

```swift
enum Screen {
    case login
    case users
}

final class AppCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var screen: Screen = .login
    private let userDefaultRepository = UserDefaultsRepository()
    private let providerFactory: BaseProviderProtocol = BaseProviderFactory()

    init() {
        if userDefaultRepository.getAccessToken() != nil {
            screen = .users
        } else {
            screen = .login
        }
    }

    func userView() -> some View {
        let store = UserStore()
        let presenter = baseProviderFactory.getUserPresenter() as! BasePresenterProtocol
        return UserView(store: store, presenter: presenter)
    }

    func loginView() -> some View {
        let store = LoginStore()
        let presenter = baseProviderFactory.getLoginPresenter() as! BasePresenterProtocol
        return LoginView(store: LoginStore(), presenter: presenter)
    }
}

@main
struct IosstarterkitApp: App {
    @StateObject var coordinator = AppCoordinator()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch coordinator.screen {
            case .login:
                coordinator.loginView()
            case .users:
                coordinator.userView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already found this solution looking around and I updated the question description with what I tried to implement following you suggestion. The problem is that I have difficulties trying to adapt it to my code. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @dave.rain You are trying to apply the approach from UIKit with storing views in properties and `UserView`. This is not the way for SwiftUI. Let me update my answer. I don't know an implementation of UserView and LoginView but better to avoid properties like `setPresenter`. You can use init injection of use a ViewModel for that.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about that but I wasn't sure. I'll try this approach.

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot.